# Localhost redirects me to http://localhost:3000/myprofile%20 instead of localhost:/3000/myprofile

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to login to my profile page after filling the login credentials but i am i being redirected to http://localhost:3000/myprofile%20,  with a 404 error.

here's is what my code looks like

// login route

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){
    if(req.body.email && req.body.password ){
        Reg.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function(error, user){
            if(error || !user){
                var err = new Error("Wrong email or password");
                err.status = 401;
                return next(err);
            }
            else{
                req.session.userId = user._id;
                return res.redirect('/myprofile ')
            }
        });

    }else{
        var err = new Error("Email and Password required");
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
    }
});
```

// GET / Profile

```
router.get('/myprofile', function(req, res, next){


    if(!req.session.userId){
        var err = new Error("Please login with your email and password");
        err.status = 403;
        return next(err);
    }
    Reg.findById(req.session.userId)
        .exec(function(error, user){
            if(error){
                return next(error);
            }else{


                return res.render('myprofile',{title:'My Profile', name:user.name, email:user.email, hobbies:user.hobbies, 
            address:user.address, medicalhistory:user.medicalhistory, allergies:user.allergies, gender:user.gender, bloodgroup:user.bloodgroup,
            birthdate:user.birthdate, country:user.country, mobileNumber:user.mobileNumber})
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: `'/myprofile '` -> `'/myprofile'`

Comment: %20 is a URL encoded space

Answer (score 2):

You have an additional blank space here in your code:

```js
else {
  req.session.userId = user._id;
  return res.redirect('/myprofile ')
  //                             ^
}
```

Remove it and you are redirected to the correct route:

```js
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.body.email && req.body.password) {
    Reg.authenticate(req.body.email, req.body.password, function(error, user) {
      if (error || !user) {
        var err = new Error("Wrong email or password");
        err.status = 401;
        return next(err);
      } else {
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/myprofile')
      }
    });

  } else {
    var err = new Error("Email and Password required");
    err.status = 401;
    return next(err);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the else part you're appending a space ( ) to the redirect function

```
   else{
        req.session.userId = user._id;
        return res.redirect('/myprofile ') // this line
    }
```

`%20` is the urlencoded character of '' space. As you probably know `32` is the ASCII of '' and `0x20` is the Hex of `32`.

Answer (score 0):

on your return( on your else condition) there is an space --> `return res.redirect('/myprofile ')` it should be like this-->  `return res.redirect('/myprofile')`